# Android sourcecode for ProgressBar.java makes no sense

Tags: java, android, android-progressbar

I am reviewing the ProgressBar.java sourcecode from Android's SDK.  On line 191 of android.widget.ProgressBar it states:

```
 mMinHeight = a.getDimensionPixelSize(R.styleable.ProgressBar_minHeight, mMinHeight));
```

Why is it using mMinHeight in the parameter list **at the same time** as it is initializing it??  Can someone shed light on this?  The full sourcecode can be located here at [grepcode](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.2_r1.1/android/widget/ProgressBar.java#ProgressBar).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See on line 171 where it calls `initProgressBar`?  That method initializes mMinHeight to the value of 24.  Then the call to `getDimensionPixelSize` uses that as the default value.

Comment: Oh, I missed that.  Sometimes its hard to peruse through all that sourcecode, and it appears as spaghetti after a while.

Answer (score 1):

The second parameter is just a default value that should be returned if `getDimensionPixelSize` is not able to find the requested value. It's common (if slightly weird) to pass in the variable you're attempting to set as the default value. Effectively, this code says "set this value if you have it, or just leave the variable as it is if you don't".

Comment: Interesting, so this is like a callback style in JavaScript?

Comment: It's not really like a javascript callback. A callback is basically just passing a function (or its address) as a parameter. The Android method here just takes a default value (which could be defined as any type, including a callback if you like) passed by the user, and returns this default value if it can't find a real value to return.